# Insert data into table, using anorm

Tags: scala, anorm

I am new to scala language, i am using anorm to insert data into DB, please give an example to insert data into my table userTable

**Table :** 
userId,
userName

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.. accept answer if it solves your problem.

```
DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
  SQL("INSERT INTO userTable values({userId},{userName})").on("userId" -> "User's id", "userName" -> "your_name").executeInsert();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
SQL("insert into userTable values({userId},{userName})").on("userId" -> value1, "userName" -> value2).executeInsert();
}
```